# Get Azure account key from corp authentication

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory

I'm trying to generate sas token for Azure [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token).

All examples I found assume the account key is known.
However, in my application I want to use Active Directory authenticate (corp) and access to the related azure account and obtain keys.

How can I get azure account keys from only corp login and password (AD)?

Comment: To generate SAS token for storage account, event hub etc you need the storage or event hub account name and the access key. this has got nothing to do with your AD account or subscription account. That said You can integrate your application with azure keyvault store your keys there and retrieve them after AD authentication. But in that case u will have to provide client id, secret of KV.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get azure account keys from only corp login and password (AD)?

If [registry an Azure Application and assign the application role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application) is acceptable,

then we could use the [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent/) SDK to get the storage account key.

```
var cred = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromUser("username", "password", "clientId", "tenantId",AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
var azure = Azure
                .Configure()
                .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                .Authenticate(credentials)
                .WithDefaultSubscription();
var key = azure.StorageAccounts.GetByResourceGroup("rgName", "storageAccountName").GetKeys().FirstOrDefault();
```

**Test result:**

[image]